# Count longest sequence of consecutive values across time in three dimensional data array (lat, lon, time)

Tags: python, arrays, count, python-xarray

This is the first time I am asking a question here, so let me know if you require more information to suggest a solution.

I have a three dimensional boolean data array (time, lat, lon), which I have processed using the xarray library in python 3. The data array I am working with includes data for one year and it has daily timesteps (365-366 days depending on whether it is a leap year or not).

The dimensions of a sample data array are shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsOK2.png), and a sample netcdf file can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/lidefi87/SO_Question/blob/main/data.nc?raw=true) and load as `da = xr.open_dataset('data.nc')`. This sample includes five time steps only.

I would like to know how long is the longest sequence of `True` values for each cell (or pixel). The output containing the longest sequence should be a two dimensional data array or data frame. So, for example, if a cell has values of `[True, True, True, False, True]`, the result I want to get for that pixel is `3` as this represents the three consecutive `True` values.

I have tried using cumulative sums across time using `da.cumsum('time')`, but this adds up all values, even if they are not consecutive, but this is not what I want.

Similar questions have been asked before for two dimensional dataframes, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794195/count-consecutives-values-in-time-series) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897265/how-to-count-longest-uninterrupted-sequence-in-pandas). But I have not been able to implement these solutions successfully in a three dimensional dataframe.

Since I am fairly new to Python and xarray in particular, I cannot figure out how I could achieve this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs a solution, I found one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61753567/convert-cumsum-output-to-binary-array-in-xarray). There, @tda suggests resetting the cumulative sum to zero every time a zero is encountered in the original data array using this line of code:
`cumulative = data.cumsum(dim='time')-data.cumsum(dim='time').where(data.values == 0).ffill(dim='time').fillna(0)`
where `data` is the original data array on which we are basing this cumulative sum calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much! I had to use this after a `resample` so I embedded your code in a function:

```
def n_longest_consecutive(ds, dim='time'):
    ds = ds.cumsum(dim=dim) - ds.cumsum(dim=dim).where(data == 0).ffill(dim=dim).fillna(0)
    return data.max(dim=dim)
```

I just deleted the `.values` inside the `where`: it forces the evaluation of `data` and the workflow is no longer 'lazy'.